# The height of td doesnt match the content

Tags: html, css

In this table, i have a table with 3 images: left, topcenter and right.
the topcenter td row is 126px, but the content image is 122px.
i tried with overflow: hidden, by giving the td a css-fixed height, but this thing just wants to have 126px height.

you can verify it by the box-shadow under the topcenter image.
it should stick at the image, not 4px below.

i am stuck here, i guess someone else sees this in 10 secs, so pls help me.

http://jsbin.com/fonemeqohe/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `display: block;` or `vertical-align` to topcenter image:

```
img {vertical-align: bottom}
```

OR

```
img {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `line-height` of the `td` to 0.

Answer (score -1):

1. you need to have the same number of cells in each row
2. your second (top center) cell has width 100% which is nonsensical
3. all cells in a row have the same height, that's the concept of a table

My two cents - stop using tables for layout and appearance, they are for data only. Use inline-block divs, for example, or float: left for divs. Or just place your images next to one another, whatever you need.

EDIT: Or combine those images in a single one and use it as a background-image for the body (or any other element suitable for your needs).

Comment: this question is already answered. its a newsletter and should work in outlook, thats why i used tables. outlook doesnt accept body background images. if you look at the html, you'll see, that i use colspan / rowspan. thats why i dont have the same number of cells in every row.

Comment: yeah, downvote my question, because you can't stand giving a bad answer. SO changes...